# Calling viewmodel methods from partial view ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewmodel

If I have a view model in this manner:

```
public class ChangePasswordVM : IChangePasswordVM
{
    public bool IsValidPassword(string password)
    {
        return password.Length >= 7;
    }

    public void SetPassword(string password)
    {
        // set password
    }
}
```

Is it then possible from a partial view to call the IsValidPassword and SetPassword method?

```
@model ViewModels.IChangePasswordVM
```

Say that I have a @Html.BeginForm and on submit I check if it is a valid password, and if it is I call SetPassword method.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - why would you call this business logic from the partial view and which is rendered before submit anyway? Should you not be doing it in the controller method processing the submit?

Comment: I am used to a more desktop-client approach where you have a viewmodel for each view which you directly communicate with to validate data you enter in the view.

I would like to have a controller which returns a view with a view model, where the view later uses the viewmodel to manipulate server-side data.

Maybe I have the wrong way of thinking here.

Comment: A view model in the context of MVVM is a different beast to a what is called a view model in MVC. In MVC you carry out actions by making Get/Post requests to controller actions. You do not have any "action" type methods in your VM.

Comment: A viewModel should just be a collection of data you want to display, and not contain any functionality. Use it to transport data into you partialview, post data back into you controller and then store it (after validation and checks etc). Everything else would be fighting against MVC, not using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all you need in this example is set specific attribute on your password property. That's all. In your example I think you can use following attribute on Password Property:

```
[MinLength(7, ErrorMessage="Password must have at least 7 characters")]
public string Password {get;set;}
```

ViewModel should be just a data which you want to bind - not a logic.So the password should be a property of your view model.